# Auto complete not working when writing a query in Toad 16

Tags: autocomplete, toad

in TOAD 16, no code autocompletes when writing a query. If ctrl+. If I do, the snippet opens. I want this to be automatic but it is not happening. Can you help? (please see the image i uploaded)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPsOL.png)

I tried the previously shared suggestions but without success